# Using JPEG as background on Android instead of PNG

Tags: android, layout, png, jpeg

I want to ask if Android accepts JPEG images instead of PNG, because PNG has bigger file size than JPEG.

I want to know how to use JPEG as background image in layout.xml file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put a `.jpg` file in your res/drawable folder and refer to it as you normally would.

For example, if you put `picture.jpg` in your drawable folder, from one of your views you could just do the following.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/picture" />
```